# How to compile constants file in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I'm trying to compile a constants file in nodejs and I have this error:

```
ERROR in src/app/esri-map/sti/sti-layers-urls.ts(1,1): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'module'.
```

the constants file (sti-layers-urls.ts):

```
module.exports = {
 GOOGLE: 'http://google.com/',
 STACKOVERFLOW: 'https://stackoverflow.com/'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In typescript you could directly export constants like this:

sti-layers-urls.ts

```js
export const GOOGLE = 'http://google.com/';
export const STACKOVERFLOW = 'https://stackoverflow.com/'
```

OR

```js
export const CONSTANTS = {
  GOOGLE: 'http://google.com/',
  STACKOVERFLOW: 'https://stackoverflow.com/'
};
```

Comment: but I want an array of constants not only one